# How to compare two fields of two different objects in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I Have two custom objects(obj1 and obj2) and two fields(Obj1field and Obj2field) in these custom objects.Now I would like to write a validation rule in obj1, which compares the two fields.I tried the below one, but there is an error.

```
Enter_Required_Quanity__c >=    $ObjectType.StorageObject__c.Fields.Quantity_Left__c
```

When I tried this the following error occurred.

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '>='. Expected Number, received Object

Comment: You can do the validation against two records (your current record obj1 and its parent - lookup field to obj2)

Comment: Can you please share any steps

Comment: Is there any relationship between obj1 and obj2

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the Validation Rule executes upon a DML event on an object. For argument's sake, we'll assume that object is `Obj1__c`

So, as long as `Obj2__c` is a parent object (via master-detail or lookup) to `Obj1__c`, then the Validation Rule would look like

```
Enter_Required_Quantity__c > Obj2__r.Quantity_Left__c
```

`Obj2__r` is the relationship name from `Obj1__c` to `Obj2__c`

Now, if `Obj2__c` is not related to `Obj1__c` via a master or lookup relationship (parent/grandparent/great-grandparent or greatgreat-grandparent), then you can't do the Validation Rule.

Validation Rules can't look down to children nor look up and then down to siblings.

Comment: But here I need to click on lookup to select the record.

Comment: @Peeter6264 - please use the edit link on your OP to amend your question with more details as it would appear I misunderstood your question